# redirect url on shared server to node.js app

Tags: node.js, directadmin

For my local theater group, I programmed a web app to sell tickets for their plays. I used node.js for the back end. They use a shared server, with the directadmin web panel. I managed to install all node.js reauirements onto the server, together with the files. I got it to run, using pm2, but now I'm stuck on how to configure the ports and the urls so you end up on that web app. Could someone help me out?

I looked at the directadmin panel, alomgside the internet, but could not find any answers to my question.

Comment: Hi, you have to ask support directly to your provider. This isn't a programming problem...  Be sure to read  [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Thank you